# iMessage sent to me by spouse shows receivers name (mine).

Tags: iphone

When I send her an iMessage there’s no problem, but on my receiving end from her, my name appears as if I sent message to myself. How may I stop this recent twist?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your post?

Comment: Are you using seperate Apple-IDs?

Comment: @JBis that would be disclosing private information.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

1. As @jksoegaard has indicated, you and your spouse are sharing an AppleID
2. You and your spouse are sharing an iPad or Mac
3. You or your spouse have gotten a contact mis-labeled
4. You and your spouse are doing research for a new comedy show

If none of those address your issue, you could Google `iMessage from spouse says it's from me`, and start reading through the responses. In any case, the number of hits from this search should give you some comfort as you'll learn you're not alone.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone’s address book dictates the name that matches a number. Check your card and your iCloud - each and every field in either could cause this mapping to take place.

You might also disable all address book sync sources. Apple iOS can pull data from all sorts of third party sources so you might be injecting bad data from linked in, Facebook, google accounts, etc...